# Created_at time are all same table relation in Laravel6

Tags: laravel

I'm studying table relation in Laravel6. Here is my code which works but suddenly all records Created_at time displayed the same `2021-08-02 11:34:30`. I'm sure that time was right. but I noticed it all same. Could you teach me how to fix please?

I would like to get the products table's created_at.

```
class ProductController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $products = Product::All();
        $products = Product::with('categori')
        ->join('creators', 'creators.id', '=', 'products.creator_id')
        ->join('categoris', 'categoris.id', '=', 'products.categori_id')
        ->join('branches', 'branches.id', '=', 'products.br_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
        ->join('colors', 'colors.id', '=', 'products.color_id')
        ->get();
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'index',
            'no'    => 1,
            'products'  => $products,
            'created_at' => created_at,
        );
        return view('product.index',$data);
    }
```

**Here is my blade file**

```
{{ $product->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

**UPDATE: Model Produt**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['title','kansu', 'customer', 'memo', 'status', 'memo2', 'color_id', 'creator_id', 'br_id','user_id' ,'categori_id'];

    public function categori() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categori::class);
    }
}
```

Produts Table image

[image]

Comment: Did you check your table?

Comment: Are `created_at` values the same for every record in the **database**? If not, show your code where and how a model is saved.

Comment: Dear @Abhishek  Thank you for helping me. Yes Table's values are fine.

Comment: Dear @Huy Phạm Thank you for helping me. I update Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `format()` method. You could try to use PHP `date_format()` to see if there is any difference.

@Bladeview:

```
{{ date_format($product->created_at, 'Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

Related docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Thank you layout looks perfect now! but still my created_at time are all same.

Comment: @bluetail `'created_at' => created_at,` is this line in your code a typo or something? I don't  see any declartion about this variable

Comment: Thank you for helping me.  I still have time problem but  Thank you I learned alot.